# three Syntax errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error, minecraft, eventhandler

I just started coding and I am now following a tutorial. I followed the exact steps in the tutorial and changed any variable to what I used. "Example: *PutNAMEHERE* to *MyNAME*"

This is the tutorial:
http://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-7/proxies/

I got three syntax errors though.

This is the piece of code that gives the errors:

```
@EventHandler
public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent e) {
proxy.postInit (e);
}
```

The errors are:

```
*Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
 EnumHeader
- Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
```

I did some research before posting this question. I thought there might be a general fix for these errors but it seems it is different for most people.

EDIT:

here is the whole code:

```
package com.loenabelle.ZAWAM;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = Main.MODID, name = Main.MODNAME, version = Main.VERSION)
public class Main {

    public static final String MODID = "ZAWAM";
    public static final String MODNAME = "TZAWAM";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0.0";

    @Instance
    public static Main instance = new Main();


    @EventHandler
    public void preInit1(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init1(FMLInitializationEvent e) {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent e) {
       //added a 1 to all but one init//         
    }
}

@SidedProxy(clientSide="com.loenabelle.ZAWAM.ClientProxy", serverSide="com.loenabelle.ZAWAM.ServerProxy") 
public static CommonProxy proxy;

@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
    proxy.preInit(e);
}

@EventHandler
public void init(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
    proxy.init(e);
}

@EventHandler
public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent e) {
    proxy.postInit (e);
    //continue and try to fix this later
}
```

Comment: Show us the complete class

Comment: There could be an error further up in the code.

Comment: Yeah java methods must be in a class, not flying around, possibles duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Syntax+error%2C+insert+%22enum+Identifier%22+to+complete+

Comment: from what i can see, the error is the space that you have on the 3rd line... between the method and the brackets. it could be something else though as well that we cannot see because you didnt add the whole code.

Comment: For some reason I made all the errors go away by opening a curly bracket after @sidedproxy [...] commonproxy proxy; and closing a curly bracket at the end of the intire class.

Comment: *For some reason* -- Yes, that is because methods cannot be *outside* of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the code above is the *closing* brace that occurs before "@SidedProxy". Up until that point, everything is inside the class `Main`. That curly brace ends the class. Code after this closing brace is not in any class at all, which is illegal for method declarations and the like. Nearly everything in Java must be inside a class.

Eclipse does basic matching braces--if you place the cursor on the opening brace of the class (`Main {`) then Eclipse will highlight the brace that ends the class. (This applies to all sets of matching braces.)